# How do I quickly inspect the source code of a function?

Tags: haskell

I am currently learning Haskell and I am using hoogle to quickly inspect the types of a function but it would be really neat to query the source code with an arbitrary function name.

For example in the haskell irc I can do

```
@src break
lambdabot> break p =  span (not . p)
```

Is there a terminal version of this? Or how do you quickly inspect the source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a large number of things you can do to extend the GHCi prompt. [This page](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/GHCi) talks about an old project called GHCi on Acid which suggests a lot of ideas. Generally, by editing your .ghcirc file you can add many command-line call-outs including to tools like commandline lambdabot/hoogle/pointfree.

Answer (score 2):

A few options, one is to do

```
cabal install lambdabot
```

and then just run it on your terminal! This is probably the nicest option. Otherwise,  you can run a local instance of Hoogle (again `cabal install hoogle`) and then view the attached source.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want, but could you also explain how I would view the attached source code of a hoogle query?

Comment: Hoogle -> Haddock -> view source. Which is a small button on the right hand side. It's generally not as useful as lambdabot though @MaikKlein